# Making a command line login application except there seems to be an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I am using this code:

```
import requests
import json
import urllib.request
import random

enteredUserName = str(input("\n\nEnter your username to start signing in ≥ "))

stuff = json.loads(requests.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/HJxYck9H").text)

# UserName = str(stuff['users'][enteredUserName]['username'])

if enteredUserName == "anonymous":
    print("\n\nYou are logging into the public account. Password for the public account is anonymous.")

enteredPassword = str(input("\n\nEnter your password to finish signing in ≥ "))

if enteredPassword == str(stuff['users'][enteredUserName]['password']):
    if enteredUserName == "anonymous":
        print("\n\nHello anonymous user. Welcome to the public account.")
    else:
        print("\n\nHello @" + enteredUserName + ". Welcome to your account.\n\nThis is your user info. Do not give it away.\nUsername is " + enteredUserName + "\nPassword is " + enteredPassword + "\n\n")
else:
    print("\n\nWrong password.")
```

The contents of the JSON on pastebin are:

```
{
  "users": {
    "anonymous": [
      {
        "password": "anonymous"
      }
    ],
    "James123": [
      {
        "password": "Jam3s"
      }
    ],
    "Jack123": [
      {
        "password": "J@ck"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I finish entering in the username and password it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Documents/Test/Test.py", line 17, in <module>
    if enteredPassword == str(stuff['users'][enteredUserName]['password']):
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I've converted everything to string and even unconverted but nothing works!

Comment: Look more carefully at the structure of the `password` field

Comment: Oh I changed that to str too

Comment: Check what `stuff` really is, probably is a json array and not a json object

Comment: @SirPythonMan Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Questions are expected to be self-contained. All information relevant to the question must be included in the question. I have included your JSON file from the link in your code.

Comment: Also, please don't edit thanks and other responses into the question. That space is for text relevant to your question.

Comment: Useful links: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
| In your json, `stuff['users'][enteredUserName]` is a `list` of `dicts` instead of a regular `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your structure:

```json
{
  "users": {
    "user_name": [ { "password": ... } ],
    ...
  }
}
```

But you access it in the wrong way, follow the steps:

1. `stuff['users']` is `dict`
2. `stuff['users']['user_name']` is a `list`

Now you can't access a list with a string (like `stuff['users']['user_name']['password']`).

You should access the list for example with:

```py
stuff['users'][enteredUserName][0]['password']
```

Or either with a `for` if you need to check more then one element

```py
for element in stuff['users']['user_name']:
  # your check here using element['password']
```